# Why was Nesmith the only one who remembers after activating the Omega 13?

Tags: galaxy-quest

Near the end of [Galaxy Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Quest), Nesmith activates the Omega 13 when most of the crew were shot by Sarris. Activating this causes time to reverse by 13 seconds.

**Why does only Nesmith remember the events that transpired?**

---

*FYI, I understand completely that it's just a comedy. There is 
no ship, there is no Beryllium Sphere, no digital conveyor...*

Comment: It's real, user35594. All of it, It's real.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In what didn't make it into the final movie but is in [the script](https://sfy.ru/?script=galaxy_quest), one part of the fans' competing theories is that the brain of the person who activates the Omega 13 isn't affected.

> KYLE
>
> As you know I strenuously disagree with this theory, Brandon. if 
>   all molecules were rearranged, then everyone would be back in 
>   time 13 seconds rendering the device useless.
>
> [...]
>
> KATELYN
>
> No because the brain of the person who triggers the Omega 13 is 
>   not affected, so THAT person still has his memory after the time 
>   jump. And everything is as it was, a chance to redeem a single 
>   mistake or misstep.
>
> BRANDON
>
> Thank you, Katelyn. Excellent.
>
> KATELYN
>
> (flattered, shy)
>
> You're welcome, Brandon.

(Source linked above.)

In the final movie, Brandon explains his theory that it's a matter rearranger. Gwen wonders what the use of only 13 seconds is, and Jason replies that 13 seconds is enough to correct a single mistake. The issue of remembering or not isn't brought up. Presumably this was simplified for the purposes of pacing, leading to the minor hole you bring up.

Comment: Brilliant, shame they didnt spend 2 seconds adding this brief explanation. Thanks :-)